# setState my response data in React.js (axios)

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios

I don't know, why I can't setState my response data of REST API. Console.log just working. Where is problem? I can't find problem in my code.

```
class RecentTransactions extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.setState = {
      recentTransactionsSender: [],
      recentTransactionsRecipient: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .all([
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/transactions/recipient/1'),
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/transactions/sender/1'),
      ])
      .then(
        axios.spread(
          (recentTransactionsRecipient, recentTransactionsSender) => {
            this.setState({
              recentTransactionsRecipient: recentTransactionsRecipient.data,
              recentTransactionsSender: recentTransactionsSender.data,
            });
          },
        ),
      )
      .catch(err => {});
  }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost you are setting the initial state incorrectly. You should be assigning the initial state to the **state** object rather than to **setState**.

```
this.state = {
  recentTransactionsSender: [],
  recentTransactionsRecipient: [],
};
```

Moreover, since you aren't doing anything in the constructor other than setting the initial state, you can remove it and instead do

```
class RecentTransactions extends Component {
    state = {
        recentTransactionsSender: [],
        recentTransactionsRecipient: [],
    };
}
```

Other than that, without having more details on what's not working it's impossible to help you any further.